# pg_restore on a single table not restoring indexes

Tags: postgresql

If I use pg_restore to restore the complete database I get all indexes for the tables. But when I try to import a single table there are never any indexes.

*to backup i run*

```
pg_dump -Fc -w database > my_database.dump
```

*to restore a single table i run*

```
pg_restore -t table_name -s my_database.dump
```

Which only returns the create table statement and missing the indexs, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `-t`, you limit the operation to the table you named. Indices are different objects and need to be selected with the `-I` (or `--index=`) selector.

Comment: How about primary keys and serial columns. These seem to get lost too.

Comment: any solution for this? I'm in a similar situacion where `pg_dump` backups all my DB but I'm unable to restore it with `pg_restore`, no indexes nor primary keys are restored.